# How to update browser URL on route changes to non-root Navigator in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to update the web URL when I use my nested Navigators in my flutter application .

The default route `/` that has one FlatButton that navigates to the `/sub` route. Then on `_generateSubRoute` -> `/second`

This is my example :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      routes: {
    // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget
        '/': (context) => Scaffold(
              body: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/sub');
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Go to sub",
                ),
              ),
            ),
// When navigating to the "/second" route, build the  SecondScreen widget.
        '/sub': (context) =>
            Scaffold(body: Column(children: [Text('/sub'), Flexible(
              child: Navigator(
                onGenerateRoute: _generateSubRoute ))]))
      });
  }

  Route _generateSubRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    if (settings.name == '/second') {
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        settings: settings,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => Text('Second screen')
      );
    }

    return MaterialPageRoute(
        settings: settings,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => Column(children: <Widget>[
          Text('/subroot/'),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/second');
            },
            child: Text(
              "Go to second",
            ))])
    );
  }
}
```

The web url doesn't work correctly in this code.
Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Try using Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("test") It should update url with //root.com/test

Comment: Hi, did you figure this out ?

Answer (score 0):

`import 'dart:html' as html;`
`html.window.history.pushState(null, "Home", "/");`

Comment: However this code may answer the question, it is a good practice to advocate your solution.